# drawing a vertical line through a control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UI like below :

[image]

Problem is at the moment the line splitting the name from the message is not visible unless the screen is filled (its basically a border on a custom control).

What I would like is for the parent control (`stackpanel`) to permanently have a line through it and not have to use the border on each `MessageControl`.

Is this possible?

Here is the code for the `stackpanel` :

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChatBoxWPF.ChatWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="402" d:DesignWidth="700" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ChatBoxWPF" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Name="Messages" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

UPDATE 1:

I tried this :

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scroll">
    <StackPanel Name="Messages" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Line StrokeThickness="1" X1="100" Y1="0" X2="100" Y2="{Binding ElementName=scroll, Path=ActualHeight}" />
        </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Without the grid. It now sometimes shows in the designer, and other times not. And when run doesn't show at all. Do I need the grid?

Comment: you can add spiltter, check this http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/05/08/How-Do-I-Add-a-Splitter-to-my-WPF-Window.aspx

Comment: @Ravi That would be horrible. He only wants graphics, not a full splitter functionality. See answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702140/draw-lines-and-circles-in-wpf (p.s Googling it took less time than it would've taken me to write your question)

Comment: @YoryeNathan that link is to my own question!

Comment: @MuhammadA LOL I don't know how that happened. Fixed link.

Comment: Re the Update: You made the Line a member of StackPanel. That won't work. The extra Grids in the answers below are essential (layering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very blunt and simple approach:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Name="Messages" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Line StrokeThickness="0.5" X1="116" X2="116" Y1="0" Stroke="Gainsboro" Y2="{Binding ElementName=ToLevelControl, Path=ActualHeight}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry its my first WPF project I didnt know it was this simple. Next n00b question, y2 needs to be the height of the stackpanel, do I do this in the code or is it also possible from xaml?

Comment: Something like `{Binding ElementName="Messages" Path=ActualHeight ..}`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, please see my update above. I didnt do ActualHeight on the Messages because that for some reason made the content inside the scroll to expand and for the scrollbar grip to show.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a 2nd layer for you background - the 2nd layer could be a simple grid or anything you like:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid ZIndex="0">
     <anything I want!>
  </Grid>
  <ScrollViewer ZIndex="1">
         <StackPanel Name="Messages" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
         </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Does stacking like this have a negative performance impact? I ask this because already Im feeling WPF is slowish rendering my custom control.

Comment: nope, shouldn't be a negetive impact or "drawing-artifact" as it calculates what is to be rendered to the screen before painting.